# How come an abstract class "DocumentBuilderFactory" allowed to instantiate new instance

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, instantiation

Recently, I have been working with XML parsers. This is just beginning for me and I managed to understand how to use DOM parser classes in java i.e. `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `DocumentBuilder` to parse an XML document.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
```

What I am asking myself is how come an abstract classes, such as `DocumentBuilderFactory` and `DocumentBuilder`, are allowed to instantiate new instances? And then in another example I see:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

1. As far as I know, you can not instantiate (in other words, create an object) for abstract and interface classes. Am I correct?
2. Do `getInstance()` and `newInstancce()` methods create instances of the above abstract classes?

Am I missing something about using an abstract class and its new Objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That method is an [*abstract factory method*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), which returns a *subclass* of `DocumentBuilder`, which is a (concrete) implementation.

The exact class of the object is not important to know, you only need to know that it's a `DocumentBuilder`. The method may return an instance decided at runtime, or predetermined as it sees fit.

If you are curious to know, you can print out the actual class like this:

```
 System.out.println(dbf.getClass());
```

---

Note that the method `newInstance()` is not to be confused with the method of the same name of `Class`, ie these two are different:

```
 // a static method of this class
 DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 

// an instance method of Class
 DocumentBuilderFactory.class.newInstance();
```

An unfortunate choice of name sure to have caused confusion.

Comment: i have added little extra to my question.

Comment: @Bohemian just curios.. the class DocumentBuilderFactory can certainly be viewed as an AbstractFactory since it exposes methods like newDocumentBuilder to return other object instances. However the DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance() is more or less a static factory method

Comment: @DevBlanked No [DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()) is ] an *abstract* factory method, because the type returned `DocumentBuilderFactory` is an *abstract` class. By definition, a factory method is *abstract* if the type returned is an interface or an abstract class, which basically means the instance returned *must* be a subclass of the declared return type.

Comment: @Bohemain  ...can u check my answer, which is at the bottom. sorry, if you don't get it at all. I hope, I took right concept to my brain.

Answer (score 3):

That is a *static abstract factory method* , which will return a subtype of `DocumentBuilderFactory` not the actual instance of `DocumentBuilderFactory` itself.It is not like what I presume, you understand :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = new DocumentBuilderFactory();
```

[DocumentBuilderFactory#newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance%28%29) , *Obtain a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory. This static method creates a new factory instance. This method uses the following ordered lookup **procedure to determine the DocumentBuilderFactory implementation class to load.***

`newInstance()` will return an instance of the implementing class(subtype) of `DocumentBuilderFactory`, which is not abstract and will assign reference to that object to 
`DocumentBuilderFactory` reference variable.

Comment: Exactly I am assuming : DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = new DocumentBuilderFactory();    . When you say "it will return subtype", I like to know subtype class. sorry I am nearly there but subtleness is over my thinking.

Comment: i got it man, i have looked into source. thanks for the help.

Comment: ....can u check my answer, which is at the bottom. sorry, if you don't get it at all. I hope, I took right concept to my brain.

Answer (score 1):

It's a static method. You can call static methods of abstract(or any class for that matter) classes without a reference to an instance..

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone, after trying below code my doubt got cleared.

> Calendar cls = Calendar.getInstance();
>   Date dt = new Date();
>   System.out.println(cls.getClass());                  //<------ 1
>           DocumentBuilderFactory dbls = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
>           System.out.println(dbls.getClass());        //<------2
>           DocumentBuilder db = dbls.newDocumentBuilder();
>           System.out.println(db.getClass());    //<--------3

And I see the follwoing output:

```
 ********Output******
   class java.util.GregorianCalendar
   class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
   class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl
```

a) static method "DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()" returns subtype class instance called "DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" .

b) "DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl" is a subclass of abstract "DocumentBuilderFacotory" class ,hence there is no problem if I give :

> DocumentBuilderFacotryImpl dbls = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
>   //-----Instead of giving DocumentBuilderFactory dbls = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
>
> and same applies to DocumentBuilderImpl db = dbls.newDocumentBuilder();
>   //---- Instead of DocumentBuilder db = dbls.bewDocumentBuilder();

Conclusion: newInstance(), newDocumentBuilder(), getInstance() returns subclass object. Although abstract class can not create new Object  , we can assign subclass object to abstract class (i.e.parent) reference variable. ex:

> Abstract class A{
>   }
>    class B extends A{
>   }

we can say:

```
 A a = new B();
```

but not

```
 A a = new A();
```

Comment: Yes, I think you have figured it out.